# pagination undefined google maps : showing multiple placeDetails

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, pagination

I know that there are a lot of topics about this, but I couldn't find my error anywhere. I am building a mobile app and I am trying to find places and display their names in a list. My code so far finds all my desired places and creates the markers for all of them, but when I try to write the names, it only writes 15-20. It starts writing the names after all the markers have been placed on the map. I searched for solutions and I've found one using "pagination", but when I tried it, it gives me the following error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasNextPage' of undefined"

This is my code for showing the places:

```
var map;
var nextPlace;

function initialize() {
    //get the current position of the device
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(search, failPosition,{timeout:10000});
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false); 

}


//called if the position is not obtained correctly
function failPosition(error) {
  alert("Your position is not available, please check your settings");

}

function search(position) {
  var lat = position.coords.latitude;
  var lon = position.coords.longitude;
  var myPos= new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 12,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon)
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

   var Types=new Array();
   var ty = window.localStorage.getItem("types");
   if(ty[0]!='0')
   {
    Types.push('restaurant');
   }
   if(ty[1]!='0')
   {
    Types.push('bar');
   }
   if(ty[2]!=0)
   {
    Types.push('night_club');
   }
  var request = {
    location: myPos,
    radius: String(window.localStorage.getItem("distance")),
    types: Types

  };

  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.radarSearch(request, callback);

}

function callback(results, status, pagination) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {

    getPlacesDetails(results); 

    if (pagination.hasNextPage) {
      sleep:2;
       pagination.nextPage();
}
  else
  {
     $('li').click(function()
        {
          alert("clicked");
        })
  }


}
}

function getPlacesDetails(places)
{
  for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i];i++) {
    var request = {
      placeId: places[i].place_id
     };
     nextPlace=places[i].place_id;
     var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

      service.getDetails(request,placesCallBack); 

      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: places[i].geometry.location,
      map: map,
      title: 'your location'});
      }

}

}
function placesCallBack(place,status){
   if (status== google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        $('#PlacesList').append('<li data="'+place.place_id+'"><h1>'+place.name+'</h1></li>').listview('refresh');
      }

  }


function onBackKeyDown() {
       window.location='MainPage.html';
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: There is a rate limit on retrieving pages. Are you accounting for that?  With your code, I get "Your position is not available, please check your settings".

Comment: That function is for getting your position, it does not have anything to do with the search. I'm not sure what you mean with "acounting for that", the code I put with "pagination" was suggested by someone for the same problem as me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using [radar search](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#radar_search_requests), which retrieves up to 200 results and does not support [pagination](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#PlaceSearchPaging), that is for the other types of [searches (NearbySearch, TextSearch)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_searches), which return up to 60 results in batches of 20..

> **Radar Search Requests**
>
> A Radar Search lets you search for places within a specified search radius by keyword, type or name. The Radar Search returns more results than a Nearby Search or Text Search, but the results contain fewer fields. You can call PlacesService.getDetails() to get more information about any of the places in the response.
>
> The PlaceResult objects returned by radarSearch() include only the following properties:
>
> - geometry.location
> - place_id

Comment: I didn't know radarSearch doesn't support pagination.I tries using a timeout to display all the details without pagination, but it doesn't work, do you know how can I display all the details?Even if I don't display the markers, te number of places displayed is the same.